# Multiple versions of same project in one GitHub repository

Tags: git, github

I am working on a project and committing to a GitHub repo. I would like to know how to add the multiple versions of the same project whenever I add a new feature like https://github.com/caveofprogramming/spring-framework-course.

In the above git repo, the author has added each work as a separate folder in the same git repo. I would like to know how to do it.

Comment: You just create a directory. It has nothing to do with git or github.

Comment: Could you please show it over here

Comment: `mkdir directoryname`?

Comment: Do you mean to say push the directory itself ?

Comment: You don't "push" directories, "push" is an operation made on commits. You don't "commit" directories either: only files can be committed (and then directories are created as needed, automatically).

Comment: But its not solving the purpose as which i have shown in the above link

Comment: I'm not sure what "purpose" you mean, I just explained how they implemented the structure at https://github.com/caveofprogramming/spring-framework-course: they just created files and committed them, no magic. Literally, in the very first commit: https://github.com/caveofprogramming/spring-framework-course/commits/master they added **all the files/directories at once**.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new branch for each feature you add to your project and push these branches to github.

```
$ git checkout -b newfeature
... make your changes ...
$ git add .
$ git commit 'description of your changes'
$ git push origin newfeature
```

Comment: The above one is a branch concept. But the author in the above link has published his works in progress as folders in the same git repo under master. How to do that.